# Where does type class inherit `.apply` in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am looking at this code

```
def loginForm = Form(mapping("username" -> text, "password" -> text)
    (LoginRequest.apply)(LoginRequest.unapply))

case class LoginRequest(username:String, password:String)
```

Here is the source code for Form in `Play`

```
def mapping[R, A1, A2](a1: (String, Mapping[A1]), 
                       a2: (String, Mapping[A2]))
                      (apply: Function2[A1, A2, R])
                      (unapply: Function1[R, Option[(A1, A2)]]): 
    Mapping[R] = {
        new ObjectMapping2(apply, unapply, a1, a2)
    }
```

I am trying to figure out what

```
LoginRequest.apply
```

actually means and what

```
ObjectMapping2(LoginRequest.apply, LoginRequest.unapply, "username" -> text, "password" -> text)
```

do

Comment: Where is the type class and how is this related to type classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LoginRequest` is a [case class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) and as such contains methods `apply` and `unapply`, inserted automatically by the compiler. Play need them to know how to construct and deconstruct your domain object from the mapping. If you had some custom code you would need a custom apply/unapply, but since you're using a case class (which is the correct practice) you can simply pass its apply and unapply functions which you get out of the box.

So, to answer your first question, `LoginRequest.apply` is an invocation of apply function available for every case class.

To answer your second question,

```
ObjectMapping2(LoginRequest.apply, LoginRequest.unapply, "username" -> text, "password" -> text)`
```

is saying that a new `LoginRequest` will be created from "username" and "password" strings by passing them to `LoginRequest.apply` which is a constructor for your `LoginRequest` case class. It also says that deconstructing of your `LoginRequest` is done using `LoginRequest.unapply`, which will return `Option[(String, String)]` (one string for each parameter, in your case username and password).

EDIT:

I've been rightfully warned in the comments to be more precise. So, when defining a case class, compiler will automatically generate `apply()` and `unapply()` in its companion object. You can always include these methods, in any companion object of any class you define. In this situation compiler does it for you. Method `apply()` is "special" in the sense that it allows a special syntax sugar: instead of invoking `Something.apply()`, it can also be invoked as simply `Something()`.

Note that `apply()` and `unapply()` are not overridden or implemented; you (or in this case the compiler) are simply defining them from scratch just like any other custom method. But it's the "trick" in the Scala compiler that allows the syntax sugar. So, if you define a method `apply()` in MyClass's companion object, you are of course allowed to call it in the usual way as `MyClass.apply(whatever)`, but also as `MyClass(whatever)` (that's the trick part).

You use this all the time even if you're sometimes not aware of it - for example, `List(1, 2, 3)` is actually desugared by the compiler into `List.apply(1, 2, 3)`. This trick allows us programmers to write prettier and more readable code (`List.apply()` is ugly, isn't it?)

Unrelated to this particular question, but let me mention that too - compiler will also add some other methods for case classes: `copy`, `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode`. Unlike `apply` and `unapply`, these methods will be added to the *class* (so instead of invoking on companion object like `apply` and `unapply`, those need to be invoked upon an instance of the case class).

Comment: good answer, but If i'm not mistaken, the `apply` method is being added to the case class because declaring case classes will automatically create a companion object for the newly created class and the companion object implements the `apply` method. I think it's worth adding to the answer, for a full explanation.

Comment: yes, compiler will add an implementation of apply() to companion object of the case class. updating the answer to be more precise.